Efficiently filtering comma separated strings in pandas/dask
I have some data which has the following shape (with header)
Name,Signal,Date
MyName,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",19-04-2024
MyName,"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10",19-04-2024

I'm interested in filtering the rows based on the sum of the array in "Signal". So I tried the following :
df = read_csv("my_csv.csv", dtype={"Signal" : "string"}, parse_dates=True)

for i in df["Signal"]:
   t = np.array([int(x) for x in i.split(",")])
   if t.sum() == 100:
       #etc

This approach raises some issues though :

How can I then record the index of the current row to then filter/drop it from my dataframe
Can this operation be sped up/done more efficiently? I was thinking of allocating a 2d numpy array and then parsing in the numbers to only allocate once but not sure this would make a difference
When using dask, which lacks a global row index, is there a more efficient way to filter the rows without allocating all the data into numpy arrays?


Is that exactly what your data looks like? Because you can't read it using read_csv without all sorts of warnings and most of the Signal values ending up in the index

@cottontail that's the thing, just one example would be looking at the sum. It would be nice if I could have the data (signal) as an array format which would be very versatile.

@Nick sorry yes you're right, I forgot to add quotes over the elements which are part of signal. I will edit now.

Having read in your dataframe, you can then convert the Signal values into a list of integers using this code:
df['Signal'] = df['Signal'].apply(lambda s:list(map(int, s.split(','))))

Output:
     Name                           Signal        Date
0  MyName  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  19-04-2024
1  MyName  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]  19-04-2024

Then you can play with your values to filter the dataframe. For example, to filter on sums:
sums = df['Signal'].apply(sum)
# 0    55
# 1    55
# Name: Signal, dtype: int64

mask = sums == 100
# 0    False
# 1    False
# Name: Signal, dtype: bool

df_filtered = df[mask]

If you want to use the sums more than once, it's probably best to save them in the dataframe e.g.
df['sum'] = df['Signal'].apply(sum)


If you just want the resultant data frame containing only rows where the sum Signal is equal to some value (i.e. 100), you can use polars for reading in the data.
import polars as pl

df = (
    pl.read_csv('path/to/file.csv')
      .with_columns(pl.col('Signal').str.split(',').cast(pl.List(pl.Int64)))
      .filter(pl.col('Signal').list.sum() == 100)
)

Comparing this to a pandas solution of using the converters argument in read_csv:
import pandas as pd

df_all = pd.read_csv(
    'path/to/file.csv', 
    converters={'Signal': lambda s: list( map(int, s.split(',')) )}
)
ix = df_all.Signal.apply(sum).eq(100)
df = df_all.loc[ix].reset_index(drop=True)

Here are the times for 1,000,000 rows:
import random
import io

data = ['Name,Signal,Date']
for i in range(1_000_000):
    n = ''.join(random.choices('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', k=8))
    s = ','.join(map(str, (random.randint(0,10) for _ in range(15))))
    d = '19-04-2024'
    data.append(f'{n},"{s}",{d}')

data_str = '\n'.join(data)

In [22]: %%timeit
    ...: df = (
    ...:     pl.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_str))
    ...:       .with_columns(pl.col('Signal').str.split(',').cast(pl.List(pl.Int64)))
    ...:       .filter(pl.col('Signal').list.sum() == 100)
    ...: )
    ...:
    ...:
635 ms ± 12.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

In [23]: %%timeit
    ...: df_all = pd.read_csv(
    ...:     io.StringIO(data_str),
    ...:     converters={'Signal': lambda s: list( map(int, s.split(',')) )}
    ...: )
    ...: ix = df_all.Signal.apply(sum).eq(100)
    ...: df = df_all.loc[ix].reset_index(drop=True)
    ...:
    ...:
2.06 s ± 53.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)


I was a little curious as to how your solution compared to my solution and the difference was 1.3 s vs 2.51 s (on Google Colab CPU instance). So the difference is not as stark as in your benchmark but your solution is still much faster.

Expanding the Signal column into a dataframe and computing row-wise sum could be an option. Then use the result to filter the source dataframe.
sums = df['Signal'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float).sum(axis=1)
df = df[sums==100].reset_index(drop=True)

Since the goal is filtering, another option is to read_csv to read specific columns and skip rows; this is a little verbose but Pandas file I/O is incredibly fast.
The idea is to read only the Signal column, process it to make it as if it where a csv file itself; then read that into a dataframe (signals_df below) and perform row-wise summation. Then read all columns of the csv again, only this time, skip rows where the sum is not equal to 100, i.e. only select rows where the sum is equal to 100.
signals = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', usecols=['Signal']).values.ravel().tolist()
signals_df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO("\n".join(signals)), header=None)
total_signals = signals_df.sum(axis=1)
# +1 is to account for the header
rows_to_skip = total_signals.index[total_signals!=100] + 1
df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', skiprows=rows_to_skip)


Based on your sample data, I am leaning toward using Regex on the input file first before loading it to a pandas's dataframe to change the separator between the columns (it is easy, efficient and keeps track of indices).

NOTE:  This answer answers your first 2 questions, the third I guess could be handled using .loc or boolean indexing, but not sure since I didn't understand it well.

Option 1

Open the input file using the Sublime text program or any text editor that offers the Regex engine.
click Ctrl+h to open the find and replace, then enter this pattern in the find section (\w+),(.*),(\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}) and this pattern in the Replace section \1;\2;\3.
The find pattern will match every line of your data and change the separator between your columns' data; a line of your data will look like this:
MyName;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;19-04-2024


NOTE:  Make sure to manually change the separator to ; between the column names, then save your input file.
Your data will look like the following:

Name;Signal;Date
MyName;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;19-04-2024
MyName;1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10;19-04-2024


with simple code of pandas you could get the sum of signals and later filter the way you want.

Here is a sample code:
temp = pd.read_csv('my_csv copy.csv', sep=";")
df = (
    temp
    .assign(
        summation = lambda df_: df_.Signal.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: sum([int(i) for i in x]))
    )
)

you will have an output like this:
  Name                Signal        Date     summation
0  MyName  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  19-04-2024         55
1  MyName  1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10  19-04-2024         55

Option 2
You could open the CSV file and read it line by line and append the lines to a pandas dataframe.

NOTE:  This might not be efficient with big data file, but since I don't know the size of your data, I thought that it is worth testing.
Here is a sample code:

df = pd.read_csv('my_csv.csv', dtype={"Signal" : "string"})
# read csv file line by line
output_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['index','name','Signal', 'Time'])
i = 0
with open('my_csv.csv', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline()
    for line in f:
        my_list = line.strip().split(',')
        singals =[int(x) for x in my_list[1:-1]]
        summation = sum(singals)
        output_df = pd.concat([
            output_df,
            pd.DataFrame([[i, my_list[0], singals,summation, my_list[-1]]], columns=['index','name','Signal', 'summation','Time'])
        ])
        i+=1
        
output_df = output_df.assign(Time = pd.to_datetime(output_df['Time'], format='%d-%m-%Y'))
output_df

the output of the code above should be:
index    name                           Signal       Time  summation
0      MyName  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 2024-04-19       55.0
1      MyName  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10] 2024-04-19       55.0

I hope this helps!

Here's my first approach. I tested this on a ~10 million line file that had 1 to 25 random integers with a string of double-quoted, comma separated values ranging from 0 to 99. The file size was ~650 MB. I used pandarallel to parallelize the apply.
You may not have pandarallel installed. It's a nice package that can be quickly installed with pip install pandarallel (see the github or this stackoverflow post for more).
On my machine, the following took ~11s with 10 cores.
import pandas as pd
from pandarallel import pandarallel
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv',parse_dates=True)
pandarallel.initialize(progress_bar=True)

df['condition'] = df.parallel_apply(
  lambda x: np.array(x.Signal.split(','),dtype=np.int_).sum() == 100,
  axis=1,
)
df_where_true = df[df['condition']]

The new DataFrame column condition allows quick masking, satisfying your first question.
For your second question, there are likely ways to further speed up an approach, but this case is simple enough that parallelism may give you sufficient performance. One concern that's addressed here is that if your Signal data are potentially different lengths, i.e., some rows have only 3 values whereas others have 10, then converting all of the data to a 2D numpy array is not feasible without zero-padding (numpy arrays require consistent shapes). The solution provided above handles heterogenous signal lengths.
For your last question, a dask implementation could look like:
import dask.dataframe as dd
...
df['condition'] = df.apply(
  lambda x: np.array(x.Signal.split(',')).astype(int).sum() == 100,
  axis=1,
  meta=bool,
).compute()
...

However, this was not automatically parallelized for me on my workstation, and took ~110s as a result.

For this case, I think there are some option that you can do:

Using the built-in capabilities of Pandas, you may effectively record the index and drop rows. To select rows depending on the total of the array in the "Signal" column, you can use boolean indexing rather than iterating over them. Once the filtered rows have been identified, you can drop them from the DataFrame by recording their index.
You can use NumPy arrays to operate directly on the "Signal" column once it has been converted.
NumPy arrays can still be utilised for effective processing when utilising Dask integration. With the help of Dask arrays, you may analyse big datasets quickly and efficiently without having to use NumPy arrays' coordinated interface.

Below is sample code you may follow to implement above option:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Read CSV file
df = pd.read_csv("my_csv.csv", parse_dates=["Date"])

# Convert "Signal" column to arrays of numpy
df["Signal"] = df["Signal"].apply(lambda x: np.array([int(i) for i in x.split(",")]))

# this section will filter rows based on sum of "Signal" column inside the array
target = 100
mask_filter = df["Signal"].apply(lambda x: x.sum() == target)

# filtered data
filtered_datas = df.index[mask_filter]

# Drop filtered rows from DataFrame
filtered_df = df.drop(filtered_datas )

# If you want to keep only filtered rows:
# filtered_df = df.loc[filtered_datas ]

print(filtered_df)

Using Dask DataFrame and Array objects in place of the same logic would be necessary when working with large datasets. Parallelization and distributed computing will be handled well by Dask. If your dataset is exceedingly large and will not fit in memory, Dask is an excellent choice.
